# popup message in android

Tags: android

i m developing an application..

i want to create a popup message that will be stable while we don't close...

I want some tutorial that help me to do a alertDialog boxes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Give me some code". Okay, that's probably the worst way to ask for help. I'll give you a pointer - look at `Toast` in the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean "will be stable while we don't close..."?

Comment: @EboMike hey be nice, maybe he ain't a native speaker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are searching for the "Dialog" box thereby you can show Alert message, confirmation message, etc. to the user.

For more info, refer this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html ,

Here a good example on Alert Dialog box: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-alertdialog-example/ .

From your commented code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();     
alt_bld.setMessage("apprika target achieve...");
alt_bld.setCancelable(false);
alt_bld.setPositiveButton("yes", new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } });
alt_bld.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub dialog.cancel(); } }); 
alt_bld.show();
```

And for showing up the Alert dialog box in the Click event, write the  `alert.show();` code inside the click listener.

Comment: @siten which click event ? listview, button or any other ? and yes, its possible to show alert dialog box on click event.

Comment: @PareshMayani Could you elaborate on the alternatives which do not require a Builder?

Comment: i didn't find any alertdialog on my android code? is there any library needed?

Comment: The code does not compile. It should be like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810084/android-alertdialog-single-button

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked Cancel so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .create();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should look for a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

[Tuturial1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

[Tutorial2](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/07/create-custom-dialog-using.html)

It will helps you.