# AlertDialog Builder OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a tyny, but annoying problem with the AlertDialog Builder.
I want to handle an item select in a custom made AlertDialog, but OnItemSelectedListener doesn't seem to pick my clicks.

Custom Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:background="#AAFFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:text="English"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/lang_english"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/borders"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:onClick="onLanguageButtonClicked" />
<View
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:text="عربى"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/lang_arabic"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/borders"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="onLanguageButtonClicked" />

<View
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#2e2e2e"/>

<TextView
    android:text="کوردی "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/lang_kurdish"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/borders"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="onLanguageButtonClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On button click I open the dialog and handle it:

```
public void onClickDrawer(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_account_language:
            handleLanguageDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.button_account_currency:
            handleCurrencyDialog();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And the handler:

```
private void handleLanguageDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_language);
    builder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new      AdapterView.
    OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int position, long id) {
            SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i("info", "pressed" + Integer.toString(position));
            restartInLocale(new Locale(preferences.getString("locale","")));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new   DialogInterface
    .OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
        });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is your button layout? when you click on button onClickDrawer is called or not?

Comment: yes, it is called and the dialog is showed. It just doesn't do anything without a positive button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5810118/7320259 try this

Comment: Try to setOnItemClick listener on the list/spinner view whichever you are using to display the list instead of builder itself. Like if you are using spinner to show the list use-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't this is correct Approach, you are making it very much complex. If I am not wrong then you are trying to show Language selection dialog for that you should follow the below given steps.

1. Create string-array inside strings.xml resource file

   ```
   <string-array name="lang">
       <item>English</item>
       <item>عربى</item>
   </string-array>
   ```
2. When you want to show alert dialog write down below code

   ```
   private void handleLanguageDialog() {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
   builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
      .setItems(R.array.lang, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()                 {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // The 'which' argument contains the index position
          // of the selected item
          switch(which)
          {
             case 0:// English
                 break;
             case 1:// عربى
                 break;
          }
      }
   });
   return builder.create();
   }
   ```

This is the simplest way to show list of languages in alert dialog and without any positive or negative button .

Comment: I like the simplicity, but please bear with me one more time. I want to trigger that on a onClick event(not listener). Where should I put the method? inside the onClick it says that is not allowed. Sorry, but I am really new to this.

Comment: Hello Boanta lonut, I have edited my answer just check. Call handleLanguageDialog() method from your onClick event and check it.

Comment: it's working exactly how I wanted, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit off. It should look like this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
        // Add action buttons
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // sign in the user ...
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
           }
       });
    return builder.create();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: It works that way, but I need it to be without a positive button. The onClick should trigger on an item selected in that dialog.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What is the user pressing to activate this "item selected"?

Comment: I see you have these onClick listeners in the layout but no "onLanguageButtonClicked" method. Maybe what you're looking for is to create that method in your Activity and run the code in there. That method will be called when the user clicks those things.

Comment: yea, I totally forgot about that method. It works that way, but now I can't dispose the dialog. Any ideas? ^_^

Comment: call dismiss() on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void handleLanguageDialog() {
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    listItems.add("English");
    listItems.add("Arabic");
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("title")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        }
                    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // sign in the user ...
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    }).show();
}
```

Comment: And how should my dialog fragment look? It opens an empty fragment this way.

Comment: just replace your handleLanguageDialog().

Answer (score 1):

Try to use setOnItemClick listener on the list/spinner view whichever you are using to display the list instead of builder itself. Like if you are using spinner to show the list use-

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);                                                                       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
            int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            commandWriter(item); 
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: add click listener to the language item in your Dialog

`onItemSelected()`  is applied for `listview` or `spinner` items your Dialog layout `dialog_language` does not have those.

Try this code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
                View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_language, null);
                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                builder.setView(myview);

                TextView english = (TextView) myview.findViewById (R.id.lang_english);
                english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do some stuff
                         SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        Log.i("info", "pressed" + Integer.toString(position));
                        restartInLocale(new Locale(preferences.getString("locale","")));
                        }
                });

                TextView arabic = (TextView) myview.findViewById (R.id.lang_arabic);
                arabic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       //do other stuff
                    }
                });


                // Add action buttons
                       builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                   builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });   

            builder.show();
```